# Review Suspension - Feedback

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I recently reviewed a post and my review was deemed incorrect. The result was I was suspended from reviewing. Here's the post in question - https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18330438.

The post was flagged as 'rude or abusive', iirc. Imo, it doesn't fall under the realm of 'rude or abusive'. It does state how Ambari Server and Ambari Agent are different.

Why was I suspended? For too many failed review audits, or manually by a moderator? And if so, why?

Trying to learn how to become a better moderator, and this really confused me.

[image]

Comment: Hmm...possible plagarism? It looks like a copy & paste!

Comment: Googling the contents indicates it's copy-&-pasted without actual attribution from the link included in the post.

Comment: count yourself lucky, the review queues are just a turing tarpit of a waste of time.

Comment: I could certainly see why someone would be concerned they were considered rude or abusive when such was not intended.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It reads too much like spam for my tastes.  Specifically, this is what raised a red flag for me:

> Ambari server runs on any one of the node in a cluster. Check this post to know How to install Ambari-server

Above all I would argue that this is a dump of copy-pasted documentation from somewhere else on the Internet, with no disclosure as to if the answerer is affiliated with the product.  I agree that the post should've been marked as spam.

In essence, in review you have to pick up on subtle nuances like this.  If the answer doesn't feel like it can stand on its own two legs without *needing* references, then that's a smell.  If it says there are links to other things and it doesn't include it, that's a fairly obvious indicator.

I'd encourage you to take the time you have to look at answers similar to this and see if they would really be suitable answers at all.  Pay *close* and *critical* attention to everything about them.  In time, you'll come to identify smells about answers which make them sit well enough into spammy territory.

Comment: Thanks, I was definitely too focused on finding 'rude or abusive' content. The post did read a little weird, and I remember thinking it might have been copy/paste from the documentation. However, it did answer the question to some extent, so would the better option have been to Edit the post to turn it into a blockquote?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody:  No.  Editing this post wouldn't have saved very much.  There's not a really good answer buried underneath some sand or sediment; they're a mound of junk on top of a mound of junk.  I personally would have flagged it as spam, or if I felt any more unsure, would have simply skipped it in review.

Comment: @brett Note that "skip" is a reasonable way to deal with something that just smells a bit.  You should really be skipping more than you accept/reject, unless you are spending a lot of time investigating the smelly ones.