# First Answers Review Suspension because of plagiarized answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension, plagiarism

IMHO, it is quite difficult to do First Answers reviews on a daily basis without getting suspended after a few days.

*For sure*, not all of my reviews were correct and some of the failures and suspensions were absolutely reasonable.

Still, I'm trying to do my best and make "good" reviews and *not* just click "Looks OK" and go on. I do really think, that I have learned my lessons from the past suspensions, which are always getting longer. Because of "fear" of suspension, I even click "Skip" whenever I have a small doubt about my reaction.

But at all, I can't really comprehend my newest suspension because of these two reviews:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/31762755
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32049679

Both answers were - in my opinion - not "perfect", but suitable and OK. Meanwhile, I see some comments about plagiarism there, which of course explain the answers being inadequate. But I wonder how I should have checked this beforehand. If an answer looks helpful to me, how should I make sure it isn't stolen from somewhere? (Of course, I could do a web search for it - but this can't be the intended solution, can it?)

So, to sum it up, this "question" is to address a few "global" and a few "personal" issues:

- How can we achieve that people trying to do good reviews - especially if it's some dozens per day - don't get suspended for reasons they cannot know of beforehand or opinion-based decisions? (Perhaps one could take into account the number of "correct" reviews.)
- How should one be able to detect plagiarism when looking at an answer (if it is not really, really obvious)?
- And for my personal case: What could I have done to not get suspended for these two tasks?

Please don't get my post wrong - it's not intended as a complaint or to express that I would feel being treated unfairly. I have faith in the Stack Overflow community and really want to contribute/give something back, but am a little frustrated because of the suspensions. I just want to understand what was going on here and how both the "logic" and I personally could improve here.

Comment: Related / possible dupe targets: [Is a plagiarism audit justified?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405181/8967612), [Are reviewers expected to research for internet-wide plagiarism in the First Answers review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418370/8967612), [How to detect plagiarism when reviewing audit answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363732/8967612)

Comment: “ Because of "fear" of suspension, I even click "Skip" whenever I have a small doubt about my reaction.” seems like it’s working then - isn’t that kind of the point of audits and skipping?

Comment: I did the alternative to skip - I just stopped reviewing!

Comment: i find the system wrong, to get banned. it should be only reserved to to serial bad choice makers. as nobody listened to me, i make like Nigel Ren, i stopped reviewing. in rare cases i stumble about en edit tat was made and i judge that, but the number is countable on two hands.

Comment: As someone who got suspended from SO for a week after downvoting crappy questions with no effort. So changed.  Then deemed to have been deliberately invalidly mass voting to close them despite the fact id say 80+% are answered by the manual. The fear is real and having been told off for getting some reviews wrong in the past I also stopped those too.   It does feel its hard to do the right thing. We want quality questions but in short if you do too much to try make it better you’re bad. (I expect to be thrown out for saying so)

Comment: @user438383 there is even a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773) to make certain amount of skips a prerequisite for reviewer badges, to help folks learn about importance of this action. [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: "IMHO, it is quite difficult to do reviews on a daily basis without getting suspended after a few days." - I process hundreds of reviews every week. I don't have a problem being suspended.  **However, there is one thing I don't do, I don't indicate that a contribution is "ok" when it's already been deleted.** Do yourself a favor and open the question in another tab.  You will stop failing obvious audits by doing that.

Comment: I unsuspended you from review. I don't think either of those had any red flags to check for plagiarism. I wish that queue wouldn't use mod-deleted answers like that. They don't reliably make good audits. Maybe it should be limited to ones with a helpful NAA flag, or something like that.

Comment: @BugFinder you're really misrepresenting what happened. First of all, you weren't suspended for the downvoting, which was on 70 percent of the questions in a specific tag over a long period of time, and unprecedented in scale.  Second, you were suspended for *blatantly invalid* close votes. Among other things, you voted "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." for a number of debugging and how-to questions. It wasn't a close call.

Comment: *"80+% are answered by the manual"* - that isn't a reason to close a question, let alone delete it.

Comment: @RyanM thats the thing. As I said. I see those questions as low quality because they are covered in the unity documentation. And so are covered by something publicly provided by the company. Therefore count as low effort or asking to be pointed at the documentation. After all we dont have an rtfm option and the answers are mainly covered.  As a long term site user i do read them. I wasn’t handing out like a bot I was reading and offered my opinion having years of experience. I know the mods disagree. But it puts me off wanting to make SO better because I no longer feel able to point things out

Comment: @BugFinder *"I no longer feel able to point things out"* ... I have a really hard time reading Ryans comment as "you're not supposed to comment". That there isn't a RTFM close reason is a very obvious indicator, that those questions aren't off-topic. You're still free to downvote and leave a comment. Misusing the close option for that isn't an option, though.

Comment: @tom no. Because I got told off for downvotes. Hence. Its hard now to feel able to do anything right.

Comment: If the questions are answered by the manual then either (1) close them as a duplicate of an existing question that asks the same thing, or (2) write an answer quoting the manual. It's not hard to do the right things on SO, it's just that the things you *want* to do - and are choosing to do - aren't the right things.

Comment: @BugFinder Like Ryan said, you weren't suspended for using downvotes. So it doesn't matter what others told you on how you should use those votes, as long as you're doing any serial voting.

Comment: @tom I agree but it was cited as part of the suspension. But I didn’t bring it up to debate it. I accepted my suspension because you can’t open a discussion. but now don’t feel I have the choices of down voting and closing because my votes were deemed incorrect. Ryan rightly pointed out they were under one tag. Yes. Because that’s the one tag I follow and feel best to answer as while I can do many others I am more out of practice or not overly interested in keeping those skills up. I only mentioned it as support for the poster as it is off putting for those trying to do the right thing.

Comment: The issue is not that you only downvoted questions with that tag, it's that you downvoted 70% of all questions with that tag.

Comment: @kaya3 That alone shouldn't be an issue and even when Ryan said that 70% for all questions in one tag hasn't happened before, it doesn't look that strange anymore when seeing that BugFinder has only 61 downvotes in total. When there are other indicators for ill-intent, like quick downvotes for all questions independent of quality or mainly for posts from one or very few users, then there could be an issue, but that percentage alone doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @Tom That's 61 downvotes after mod intervention, and I would guess that means that a large number of votes were removed. (The tag in question appears to be [tag:c#], so 61 downvotes can't possibly be 70% of all questions over a sustained period of time.) I didn't say that that alone is a problem, I pointed out that BugFinder misstated what the issue was.

Comment: Maybe we need a separate plagiarism queue.

Comment: @user4581301 No, we need two things; we need a slightly better audit system where mods or possibly even trusted users (20k privilege, not some weird abstract definition; or lower, whatever makes sense) contribute to what goes in the audit pool, and for plagiarism specifically, we need automatic tooling. We've already posted a request internally asking for such tooling, but whether we get that in the near foreseeable future is not looking promising (in my biased opinion). Only mods have the necessary tools to deal with users who repeatedly plagiarise, so a queue for it doesn't make sense

Comment: At the moment, plagiarism can and should be mod flagged if detected. As I commented on the answer, though, doing so isn't a requirement for review queues. We'll take care of the posts and users. That said, if you want to help out and have some spare flags (and time) when you detect plagiarism, check some more posts by that user. Mods do that anyway, but a few extra flags (with the source included in the flag) substantially helps with speeding up handling on our end, at least while plagiarism tooling remains non-existent

Comment: Shoot. I was expecting something more like "Seriously? What, we need a queue for everything?" You mods treat me too well.

Comment: Honestly, if SE shoots down the internal plagiarism tooling proposal, I'm in favor of a queue for at least reporting it to mods. It's a lot to ask of the reviewers though, and we're already short on reviewer resources, and all other curating resources for that matter (which also falls partly on SE, but we're not getting a lot of help from them while they're busy with collectives and first questions with extra steps and higher volume). What you're seeing in this question here is really three problems; lack of plagiarism tooling, bad queue systems, and poor reviewer onboarding, and (1/2)

Comment: all of them are, in theory, SE's job. The community can only do so much for onboarding, and as evidenced by a few of the large organizations (SOBotics, SOCVR, Charcoal, etc.) struggling to expand, the community does not have a lot to go on. A plagiarism check queue, to me anyway, is best used as an absolute last resort if SE stops caring about this too, and doesn't want to pay for it. We do benefit from some queues, in my opinion, and there's a few more I'd like to see. Plagiarism specifically, though, is one I don't want to see, not because it's a bad queue, but because we _shouldn't_ need it

Comment: We shouldn't have to throw reviewers at this particular problem, when this is one of the few areas that could be done by a machine with an auto-flag. Plagiarism checking is even a mostly solved problem, and there's a number of companies offering it as a service. Why we don't have one integrated is something I'll never understand. The moderation system was unfortunately never intended for the volume of content Stack Overflow gets, though, and that problem isn't going anywhere, regardless of how many times we say it. SE needs to get more involved in this, but they don't, so here we are

Comment: Unless there is something I miss here, there *were* absolute red flags: there is one comment under each question, older than the failed review. Under the first one: "Plagiarized from pub.dev/packages/platform_detect2/example – Ryan M♦ Apr 26 at 23:50", and under the second one: "Copied without attribution from hackernoon.com/… – Ryan M♦ Jun 2 at 12:44". Having a look at the comments is often useful when there is a problem with a post.

Comment: Wow... I had not supposed that this would trigger such an amount of reactions and start this discussion! First of all, thanks to all of you for your helpful comments and votes! This is part of what I meant by "having faith in Stack Overflow" - constructive discussions and help of the community! And, of course, thank you @RyanM for unsuspending me!
As I see, I might indeed have pointed out some improvement opportunitys concering the "background logic" and have as well picked up some personal tipps and learning. That was exactly the sense of my post, so thank you all again!

Comment: Opening the question in a separate tab feels a little like "cheating" to me, but I think, I will use this trick in the future, if in doubt. To be honest, I really can't tell if the "red flag comments" were displayed at the time of my review. If so and I have really overlooked them, I admit that the fault was mostly on my side. Anyway, as stated above, I got the input and answers I was hoping for and looking forward to go on with Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille for the record, when an active audit is displayed (read: before it's completed), the comments are often hidden. The comments being there doesn't mean they're useful from within the audit, and going out of the queue to check them alone is enough to confirm it's an audit (because the post is deleted)

Comment: @ahuemmer Opening it in a tab is a perfectly valid approach, for  the record. The audits are mostly there to make sure you aren't just hitting one button for all reviews without reading anything. There's countless ways around audits, and they're by design, because audits aren't designed to be hard to discover. I'd say they're not designed to be hard, but they are because of the bad audits (again except in suggested edits). They're mostly just there to make sure you're paying attention, and opening the post in a new tab because you suspect an audit _is_ paying attention

Comment: OK @ZoestandswithUkraine, thank you very much for making both of the points clear to me! :) I highly appreciate the help of you and all the Mods and your work to keep things good and aid people like me!

Comment: IMO - Just do NOT review anything at all on SO. No point taking stress for no reason and getting suspended too. I used to do it but not anymore. I don't see a point.

Comment: *checks watch* Yup, it's time for the monthly "feature X of Stack Overflow is broken and Stack Exchange Inc. still doesn't care about fixing it" question. This month it's *spins roulette wheel* reviews!

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine: Related: An MSE question from 2013, *"[Automate on-site plagiarism detection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171876/)"*

Comment: I have just stopped reviewing entirely on SO because I kept getting banned for failing audits by clicking "Share Feedback" as an option where this was an appropriate action. Mods kept reversing the ban, but as you said each time the ban just kept increasing in time. After being banned for a month, and having mods reverse bans twice before, I just gave up on it. It's not worth your time!

Comment: I stopped reviewing due to the red dot never going away. Easier to just adblock it

Answer (score 62):

Those reviews are sensible and I'm not sure if the first one was even plagiarism since the link to the (open?) source was provided. When it comes to plagiarism: if you can find it, great. If you can't, you should at least not get punished for it. In particular, expect plagiarism when doing tag wiki suggested edit reviews.

Anyway, this post and literally countless before it keep showing that ***posts deleted by diamond moderators are not suitable for review audits!*** Very often diamond mods have much more insight into an issue than regular reviewers when they chose to delete a post. We shouldn't need to go to the actual post to check "huh is this an audit" every single time, that makes reviewing even slower and more tedious.

The solution to this problem is to boycott reviews until the audits are fixed, because nothing short of a complete disaster will make SO the company interested in improving the audit system. Let them hire paid staff to do the reviews if they can't be bothered to fix the audits.

Comment: Oh and if you want to change SO, don't forget to post non-constructive whining on Twitter rather than constructive feature requests on meta.so.

Comment: "Anyway, this post and literally countless before it keep showing that posts deleted by diamond moderators are not suitable for review audits!" - eh, we also delete huge quantities of bog-standard NAAs, many of which are prime audit candidates

Comment: `The solution to this problem is to boycott reviews until the audits are fixed` That's a excellent way to put it. Willingness to review under any circumstances on part of volunteers is part of the problem. Probably less than 1% users clear up most of the review queues. I believe this results in lack of diversity and very low quality reviews by overburdened volunteers.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine So maybe give the mods an option to say "not suitable for audit" upon deletion. Since the kind of deletes that aren't suitable are often special cases: spammer/sock pup accounts etc.

Comment: Re *"...if the first one was even plagiarism since the link to the (open?) source was provided"*: Related is *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326)*.

Comment: *"I'm not sure if the first one was even plagiarism since the link to the (open?) source was provided"* It was plagiarism, for two reasons: 1) There's zero indication that the link is the source.  Burying a random link that happens to have the source *somewhere* in the post is *not* attribution.  2) It's not even the right page.  The code was copied from the example page, not the page they linked.

Comment: @Lundin *"So maybe give the mods an option to say "not suitable for audit""* - you are absolutely right, but it's essentially pointless to suggest it. What you suggest essentially means overhauling the current audit system and then especially how audits are picked. Good luck with that. No, it is terrible and it is going to stay terrible. the only way forward is whatever can be done to persuade people to just chew through it. Suck it up.

Comment: Yep, I also had "mixed Feelings" about the 1st Answer, with Link provided where it was easy to find the Source of the Code. Not enough Code => gets flagged as "Link Only Answer"; too much Code => Plagiarism, ah-ah...! This Answer could have been salvaged... // The 2nd one was obvious "Fake Content" to me and has nothing to do with "Plagiarism", this is how "Fake Content" works... I've already (custom) flagged some (much more obvious) Fake Content, Flag(s) declined (because I didn't use the "magic" "P"-Word), this one got deleted by a Mod, weird to see it then being reused for Audits...

Comment: Side note: Getting rid of the Mods is not a viable solution to the problem of reviewing complicated Mod-deleted posts.

Comment: @user4581301 Did someone suggest getting rid of moderators?!

Comment: @TylerH Someone will. I'm just trying to head that absurdity off at the pass.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not a fan of adding another button or checkbox or whatever. SE is already busy throwing keybinds out the window; the new popups are not at all keyboard friendly, with support ranging from mediocre to non-existent. We do a lot of deletions; adding another click is a substantial slowdown at the scale we operate. I would still like to see mods and users [have more of a say](/questions/418792/#comment915490_418792), but a button to remove any post from the audit pool is half the job. That said, a button like that is after the fact, at which point, the damage has already been done

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine The default option would be "suitable for audit", I would imagine. But diamond moderators won't get less work if user moderators get review banned and fed up with reviews because of the broken audits.

Answer (score 6):

I've posted a feature request with one possible solution to this problem:

[Don't use answers with a "Very low quality" flag on them as review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379748/165261)

I believe this would address the situation, since it would avoid at least the vast majority of answers that are deleted by moderators for non-obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Both failed review audits you linked in your question had an indicator that something more than a "trivial" glance at the post in the queue itself was required. I'm referring to the "X answers" information posted near the left, just under the "Review the following answer" header.

In the first case, this showed **16 answers**. Now, although I can't categorically say that you should be searching the *entire internet* to check for plagiarism<sup>1</sup>, in the case of a new answer posted when there are so many others, then a view of those other answers is *certainly* required, to check that the new answer is unique, and not copied from one of those. Although viewing those other answers from the review itself (middle tab) would maybe not have helped in that case, opening up the post in a new window (by clicking on the post title) would have *immediately* revealed the audit for what it was.

In the second case, the indicator showed **0 answers**. This should have rung one or more alarm bells – and, again, opening up the post in a new window would have resolved that issue.

Now, while viewing each and every post you review in its own right (that is, not just from the review queue) is not something I would necessarily suggest as a matter of course, it ***is*** a technique you should use in any case where something looks 'odd', in terms of the information presented. For all audits, there will be a deliberate 'lie' in one or more of the statistics presented for the post; in fact, that is how (I think) user-scripts that detect audits work – but I'm not suggesting you use such a script to help dodge audits. (In fact, I think such scripts should not be allowed, at all.)

---

<sup>1</sup> But note: For those reviewers with 5k or more reputation points, such checking for "internet-wide" plagiarism **is an absolute requirement** when reviewing suggested edits to tag-Wikis and their excerpts. See, for example: [Let's stop tag wiki plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313486/10871073). The plagiarism issue for First and Late Answers is a bit more subjective, but a *really good* reviewer will do at least a rudimentary check, like a quick Google search.

Comment: A question having several answers can increase the chance that a new answer is just a copy of an old one, yes, but I really don't see how both "alarm bells" would have helped in detecting plagiarism from a third-party-site. So this answers boils down to just "open the actual question in a new tab" and this is a good advice for every review, not just one with many answers or none.

Comment: the second can't raise any bells, it looks perfectly fine and tries to answer the question and is well formulated, i wouldn't also google the text, that is not what the review is for

Comment: @nbk The alarm bell in the second case is that the information provided indicated that there was no answer. This was a review for an answer, so something fishy is happening. Opening up the post in its own window would have revealed the audit.

Comment: the review should help the mods and admins and filter many thinks out and leave only the "bad" to be reviewed by them, and as i many many times stated, we can give only our **opinion** about a question or answer, a ban is far to harsh for time spend

Comment: @nbk Yes, I think this review suspension was unfair and unfortunate. Ryan has now lifted the suspension, so that's good. However, the OP also asked for advice/tips on how to avoid these audit-imposed suspensions, so I gave some.

Comment: Also worth noting that suggested edits is the only queue where plagiarism checking is a hard requirement. It isn't for whichever queue this was again. It was an audit fail to begin with, and as is well-known, the audit system isn't great at picking review tasks for audits. Blame SE for that one. Outside suggested edits, audits are a mixed barrel. In fact, all queues that aren't suggested edits regularly have bad audits that are outright wrong (notably in the close vote queue), or that are poorly picked (particularly all the answer related ones)

Comment: Of course, it'd be nice if reviewers took the time to check answers for plagiarism, at least until we get some automatic plagiarism tooling so we don't have to waste as much manual work on it, but unless SE steamrolls us, plagiarism checking in review will remain a nice bonus, and not a hard requirement

Comment: As the review also contains a comment (by a mod!) that the answer was plagiarized, I think that is also a sign you should do some more work to verify it, or just skip.

Comment: Thank you, @AdrianMole, for your answer! I agree that the comments were "red flags" and - as stated above - can't remember whether they were displayed when I made my decisions. Nevertheless, I also agree with Tom and nbk that the other alarm bells for both the answers seem a little questionable or - at least - very well hidden to me. Anyway, in the future I'll make use of the suggestion given by you and others and review the question on its own, hopefully this will minimize my amount of failures.

Comment: @Mark I'm not 100% sure but I'm fairly certain that comments aren't displayed in the actual audit for "known bad" posts.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel repeating my comment [on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418792/review-suspension-because-of-plagiarized-answers?noredirect=1#comment915510_418792), the comments may not have been there during the review. Comments are often (or always, I lose track) hidden in audits, so it being there now doesn't mean it was when OP reviewed the audit. Quite a few detail are hidden or randomized in an audit, and comments being hidden is one of those. The point being, context you see now doesn't necessarily help the reviewer during the actual audit.

Comment: @AdrianMole Hmm, I thought the review links as used in the post always shows the answer as used during the review.

Comment: @Mark If you mean the links to the 'past' review as presented in this question, then no. They show what would have been shown to the reviewer *after* the audit.

Comment: First post audits are there to check for spam, crap, confused beginner users etc. Checking for plagiarism isn't expected unless there are very good reasons to suspect it. These very simply very bad audits.

Comment: @AdrianMole Reviewing should not include having to "spot the audit", nor should it be necessary to do secondary research. If you need to spot the audit in order to reliably pass it, then the audit is not doing its job. Secondly, volunteers wade through seas of questions and answers (many of which are probably mediocre and worse, or they wouldn't be in the queue), so the goal should be to provide them - at a glance - with all the information they need.

Comment: @CharonX I entirely agree! In an ideal world, audits should be passed/failed on the reviewers' assessments of the post **content**, and nothing more. However, the audit system is ... um ... *not ideal*. So, until or unless the system is fixed, I occasionally proffer some "tips" to help prevent otherwise decent/conscientious reviewers from being suspended from making their valuable curation efforts by a deeply flawed system.